# Bash Script wont launch GUI at startup

Tags: boot, gui

I need to launch a couple programs on startup, and I wrote a bash script to do so as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Starting up" >> "/home/pi/Desktop/startup-log"

CONTROLS_DIRECTORY="/home/pi/Desktop/MMAC_Control_Code"

sleep 15s 

echo "Launching software Daemon" >> "/home/pi/Desktop/startup-log"

lxterminal -l -e "python '$CONTROLS_DIRECTORY/Software Daemon/main.py'" &

sleep 60s

echo "Launching UI" >> "/home/pi/Desktop/startup-log"

chromium-browser -kiosk "$CONTROLS_DIRECTORY/RPi_Control_Panel/index.html" 

echo "Done " >> "/home/pi/Desktop/startup-log"
```

When I run the script in terminal with sh, it works as expected, opening main.py in a new terminal window and index.html in a browser window, and adds logging information to the startup log.

I have attempted to run the script at startup using chrontab, and using rc.local. With both methods I see the debugging information written into the logging file which tells me the script is being run, but neither method is actually launching any GUIs.

I added the first `sleep 15s` line because I figured it was launching before the GUI was ready. I also tried launching a script at startup which in turn launched this script after a time delay, not sure why that would have been any different, but I tried it anyways (with no change in results).

If anyone has any suggestions for getting this to work, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: There are many variant of this question answered here.  You won't get a GUI running like this.  Where would it display?

Comment: @Brick Great find, that question got me on the right track